# CakePHP 4 excluding selected MissingControllerException

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP 4 how can I completelly exclude from logging a selected MissingControllerException which occurs for Controller class called MyImg? I want to have all other MissingControllerException errors reported (just but the one for Controller class called MyImg)

Comment: Create own MissingControllerException and exclude that controller Read more: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/errors.html#custom-exceptionrenderer

Comment: I tried to write own function missingController as you suggested, the page is rendered but the log is still added to error.log. My purpose is not to have such log reported in error.log

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a custom ErrorLogger.

```
'Error' => [
    'logger' => \App\Error\ErrorLogger::class,
    'log' => true,
    ...
],
```

Now create the class ErrorLogger in the src/Error folder:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Error;

use Cake\Controller\Exception\MissingControllerException;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Throwable;

class ErrorLogger extends \Cake\Error\ErrorLogger
{
    public function logException(Throwable $exception, ?ServerRequestInterface $request = null, bool $includeTrace = false): void
    {
        if ($request !== null) {
            if ($exception instanceof MissingControllerException) {
                $requestTarget = $request->getRequestTarget();

                $checkUrlStarts = [
                    '/myimg',
                ];

                foreach ($checkUrlStarts as $urlStart) {
                    if (str_starts_with($requestTarget, $urlStart)) {
                        // skip logging
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        parent::logException($exception, $request, $includeTrace);
    }
}
```